# Cast a long to a function pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers, c89

I have the following code:

```
long fp = ...
void (*ptr)(long, char*, char*) = fp;
```

The long `fp` is a correct function pointer, which comes in as a long. I am getting the standard "makes pointer from int without a cast" warning. I want to be able to compile with:

```
-std=iso9899:1990 -pedantic-errors
```

which turns that warning into an error. The question is: what is the correct cast? I have tried various guesses, e.g.:

```
void (*ptr)(long, char*, char*) = (void)(*)(long, char*, char*) fp;
```

But can't seem to find the right one.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Cast between integers and function pointers?

Comment: If the `fp` is a correct function pointer to begin with, how come it's stored in a long? Maybe you should concentrate on getting the input right instead of trying to come up with a kludge afterwards.

Comment: I'd appreciate the answer to the question on the cast rather than a re-design. JNI introduces a multitude of sins, of which this is the least.

Comment: @MrLister: there are times where it doesn't depend on you. In Windows programming it's common practice to pass around pointers of any kind inside the parameters of the wndproc, which are guaranteed to be big enough for this stuff. Probably OP is using a library that does stuff like that.

Comment: Also the dlsym-call (POSIX) and GetProcAddress (Windows) makes you cast integers to function pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "correct" cast is:

```
void (*ptr)(long, char*, char*) = (void (*)(long, char*, char*))fp;
```

Obviously, this can be tidied up with a suitable typedef.

But either way, the result of this is implementation-defined.  If you can, avoid this, and maintain the pointer in a pointer type.  Next best thing would be to use `intptr_t` if it's available.

Answer (score 7):

Probably it's something like:

```
void (* ptr)(long, char, char *) = (void (*)(long, char, char *))fp;
```

but my suggestion is to use a `typedef` and forget about all this mess:

```
typedef void (* fnPtr)(long, char, char*);
fnPtr ptr = (fnPtr) fp;
```

Answer (score 4):

The only "correct" way is not to cast at all, but rather copy the binary representation:

```
long fp;
void (*ptr)(long, char*, char*);

memcpy(&ptr, &fp, sizeof ptr);
```

Comment: Except it catastrophically fails when sizeof(long) != sizeof(ptr).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is, that ANSI-C does not allow this, despite the countless C-APIs out there relying on this feature. Therefore, you will likely run into trouble when compiling with `-pedantic`.
As was hinted by other posters, you can cheat around the cast by using things like `memcpy()` or a union type for casting.

By the way, POSIX guarantees that this will work, so the part about 'implementation-defined results' gets a lot less scary.

Comment: C99 explicitly allows this, it just states that the results are implementation-defined.

Comment: Cool, I did not know that. I'm mostly a C++ guy, so I'm more familiar with C89, which afaik did not allow it.